# access querystring values when using ServiceStack public override object OnGet

Tags: servicestack

I am setting up my frist ServiceStack site and having a bit of an issue with accessing Query String values from my URL

```
  public override object OnGet(MyModel.Product request)
        {
            if (request.ItemID != null)
            {
                return Repo.MyRepo.GetProduct(request.ManufacturerID, request.ItemID);
            }

            return Repo.MyRepo.GetProducts(request.ManufacturerID, request.Page, request.PageSize, request.tStamp);
        }
```

The parameters Page, PageSize and tStamp are not properties on my object but I need them to call the SP I use to get my data.  How can I access those?  Seems like I am missing something really simple here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using the [ServiceStack's New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) for future services. When you inherit a `Service` class you can access the QueryString with:

```
public object Get(MyModel.Product request)
{
    var value = base.Request.QueryString["key"];
}
```